# Android OpenGL Point Clouds

Tags: android, opengl-es, point-clouds

I've been trying to use

```
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_POINTS, 4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vertexBuffer);
```

to draw 4 points on my screen with a vertex buffer, but I can't get it to work. All I want to draw is points, because eventually I want to make a point cloud display. If I have a large number of points (eventually), **is vertex buffer the way to go?** They won't be changing, but I will want to change the perspective and scale at which they are viewed.

vertexBuffer setup:

```
private float vertices[] = {
    -3.0f,  1.0f, -2.0f,  // 0, Top Left
    -3.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,  // 1, Bottom Left
    -2.0f, -1.0f, -2.0f,  // 2, Bottom Right
    -2.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,  // 3, Top Right
    };


// Our vertex buffer.
private FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices.length * 4);
vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();
vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
vertexBuffer.position(0);
```

This is my current draw call for my points (I don't want indices because shape drawing order doesn't matter to me):

```
public void draw(GL10 gl) {
    // Enabled the vertices buffer for writing and to be used during 
    // rendering.
    gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    gl.glPointSize(3);

    // Specifies the location and data format of an array of vertex
    // coordinates to use when rendering.
    gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);

    gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_POINTS, 4, 
             GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, vertexBuffer);

    // Disable the vertices buffer.
    gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    // Disable face culling.
    gl.glDisable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
}
```

The program currently crashes when I call draw();

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You make completely wrong use of `glDrawElements`. This function wants an index array containing indices into the vertex arrays and not the vertex data itself (that's what `glVertexPointer` is for). Either use

```
private unsigned byte indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
...
gl.glDrawElements(GL10.GL_POINTS, 4, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, indices);
```

But in your case you just render all points and don't need any indices, so you can just call

```
gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_POINTS, 0, 4);
```

instead of `glDrawElements`.

**EDIT:** The specific reason it crashes is that `glDrawElements` interprets the supplied `vertexBuffer` as an array of 4 bytes and these bytes reference vertices out of the range of your vertex data (0 to 3).

Comment: Thanks Christian, what you said does make sense.

However, it still crashes. After researching a lot, I can't figure out why. I threw up the small java file here, if you can scan it for me: http://www.qfpost.com/download.do?get=02700a1c0975664801e60c1cccfd6d02

Comment: @RedLeader You don't have to draw `vertices.length` (12) vertices but only 4, as every vertex is made of 3 floats (as specified in your `glVertexPointer` call). So either use `vertices.length/3` or just `4` as third argument to `glDrawArrays`.

Comment: Understood. Both ways result in Null Pointer exception though. I'm calling the draw(gl) function directly and it fails at some point in the call.

Comment: @RedLeader By the way, no need to set the front face convention when just drawing points (which don't have an orientation).

Comment: @Christian Rau

Yeah I know I've been trimming down the code as I go getting rid of what I shouldn't need. It seems like it should be working fine but IDK anymore.

Comment: @Christian Rau

Calling .draw() on this file (which I based it off of) works fine, so it has to be something in the PointCloud.java file I linked earlier

See working file: http://www.qfpost.com/download.do?get=49f5c7c63d36000ebdcca298c9ffee20

Comment: @RedLeader Another reason could be, that at another point of your program you enable another vertex array (like e.g. GL_COLOR_ARRAY or something) and don't disable it again. So glDrawArrays tries to use an array, whose data might have already been destroyed. I could look at your other parts of the code, but only if it's not too much.

Comment: @Christian Rau Thank you. This would be the last file, and the direct run out of my Activity. You can see I commented out the drawing of the Square and drew my point cloud instead(ln 66). LINK: http://www.qfpost.com/download.do?get=45e01a4ad7c412474c0fdb228da75e18

Comment: @RedLeader I think you forgot to construct the `ptCloud` object. Just add `ptCloud = new PointCloud()` to the constructor of your activity. So the error is not in the `draw` function, but the function call itself.

Comment: @Christian Rau -- Good lord. I'm so sorry for wasting your time and so thankful for your help. Yes, that works now. Thank you!